# Is it faster to Merge a (typed) dataset or replace it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm trying to get a little extra performance out of a form with controls bound to a binding source. Is it faster to replace the bound dataset

`dataset1 = returnedDataset`

or to clear the existing dataset and merge it?

`dataset1.clear
dataset1.merge(retunedDataset)`

I am using typed datasets in VS2010.

Comment: In my experience, replacing it like you have will be much faster.  Merge seems to be very slow, especially if you have EnforceConstraints set to True because it has to verify that the merge won't cause constraint violations.

Comment: I'd imagine the answer is *it depends*. How how many controls are we talking here? How big is this dataset? There may be a point of diminishing returns where overheads and payloads outweigh each other. The best way to answer your question is to test each method, using a StopWatch to time each one.